# Can I get an extended class object as a result of an SQLAlchemy relationship?

Tags: python, inheritance, sqlalchemy, relationship

I have the following structure for my Python project:

```
app/
├─ classes/
│  ├─ person
│  ├─ address
├─ database.py
├─ main.py
├─ models.py
```

database.py contains the connection details and creates the engine and session to be used:

```
# database.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, sessionmaker, scoped_session

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite://', pool_pre_ping=True)

session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
ScopedSession = scoped_session(session_factory)


class Repr:
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        # custom implementation of the __repr__ method
        print('some text')
```

models.py has the actual table definitions and relationships between the tables:

```
# models.py
from database import Base, Repr, engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Text


class PersonDB(Base, Repr):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    address_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('address.id'), nullable=False)
    first_name = Column(String(45))
    last_name = Column(String(45))
    # relationships
    address = relationship('AddressDB', backref=backref('persons'))


class AddressDB(Base, Repr):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    street = Column(Text)
    city = Column(Text)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

In the classes folder each table is added as its own file inheriting from the relevant table class in models.py and potentially extending it with additional methods and properties and otherwise merely representing an alias to be imported from classes:

```
# person.py
from models import PersonDB


class Person(PersonDB):
    @property
    def full_name(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
```

```
# address.py
from models import AddressDB


class Address(AddressDB):
    # no changes to the base class required.
    # The class merely exist as an alias importable from classes.
    pass
```

I like this approach because it separates the extended logic from the base table classes and it keeps the individual files more manageable and encapsulates it. However the problem with this is that if I use a relationship to get from one table to another it returns the base class rather than the extended class meaning I can't use additionally implemented properties or methods.
Example:

```
for p in a.persons:
    print(p.full_name)  # Error: p is PersonDB not Person object
```

Is there a way around this or should I reconsider my approach? Ideally it would work seamlessly i.e. the relationship is changed in a way that a.persons returns a list of Person objects rather than having to somehow convert a PersonDB object into a Person object in the code that calls a.persons.

Comment: I'd consider using an imperative mapping, or mapping to dataclasses rather than declarative. [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapper_config.html#orm-mapped-class-configuration)

Comment: How would that benefit me and will that help me in any way with the issue described above? The way I understand it declarative and imperative mapping are basically two different ways to do the same thing.

Comment: Using imperative mapping would allow your mapped class would not include the columns, although it would need to include the relationship configuration. You could omit the extended class and expose the mapped class directly.  If you are sold on the extended class you could consider creating [custom collections](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/collection_api.html#custom-collection-implementations) to round-trip between types.  Yet another option could be to use marshmallow or pydantic models as your business objects instead of the extended type.